# How to click on drop down with on-toggle property

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, protractor

```
  <div ng-if="domainList.length>1" class="form-group ng-scope">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label translate="ZillaMain.Authentication" class="ng-scope">Authentication</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <label uib-dropdown="" keyboard-nav="true" on-toggle="toggled(open)" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" tabindex="0" aria-label="" uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <!-- ngIf: authentication_domain -->
                        <!-- ngIf: !authentication_domain --><h3 ng-if="!authentication_domain" class="ng-scope">
                            <span translate="ZillaMain.Select" class="ng-scope">Select</span>
                            <i class="icon angle-down-icon"></i>
                        </h3><!-- end ngIf: !authentication_domain -->
                    </a>
  ------
  ------
  ------
```

With the above mentioned code I am trying to clcik on the dropdown:

```
this.AuthDD = element(by.css('[on-toggle="toggled(open)"]'));

AuthDD.click();
```

But this does not click on the drop down and My test does not fail also... I am not sure what is wrong with it.

I have also tried changing the locator by: `element(by.css('a.dropdown-toggle'));` or `element(by.css('[translate="ZillaMain.Select"]'));` but it does not clcik on the dropdown.

Is there any different way available in protractor to click on a dropdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by making following changes:

```
 this.AuthDD = element(by.css('i.angle-down-icon'));

 AuthDD.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd improve the way you are targeting the dropdown (I think your locator is too broad in general - might not be too broad in the context of your page, but I don't have that to work with) and point the locator to the `a` element enforcing the reliability with the appropriate *wait condition*:

```
var authDropdown = element(by.xpath("//label[. = 'Authentication']/following::label[@class = 'dropdown']/a"));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(authDropdown), 5000);
authDropdown.click();
```

We are using this kind of XPath expression because we want to target not just any dropdown toggle link, but the one coming after the "Authentication" label.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned changes but still dropdown is not clickable.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. This dropdown is on Login page of my application test does not fail at  `authDropdown.click();` steps but it does not login because dropdown is not clicked and option is not selected from the dropdown.

Comment: @soniasharma okay, quick question - what happens if you do `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", authDropdown);`?

Comment: Still the same issue dropdown does not get clicked and will not login.

Comment: just out of curiosity I want to know will `.click()` will work even if element does not have `ng-click` property associated with it. as you can see in the above code there is no `ng-click` property associated with the dropdown.                                                                                      IS this the reason dropdown is not getting clicked?

Comment: Also if I identify this dropdown and use `isPresent()` or `isDisplayed()` dropdown is getting identified but it just not getting clicked.

Comment: @soniasharma well, it is difficult to tell what exactly the problem is without actually being able to test that..kind of a guessing game, but it's all understandable. And no, there is no need for `ng-click` for the `click()` method to work. That might be one of the possible reasons - we are simply not clicking the correct element..